# Last updated date on custom data extension created in salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I've created a data extension in marketing cloud based on sql query. I update this data extension manually on need basis (usually one or two times in a month).

Logic for data extension - 
1. Data upload through sql query in DE
2. update logic - Overwrite

When I go to data extension, last updated date same as created date of data extension (First time created date) and it shows data extension was never refreshed.

Q1. Why it doesn't change last updated date? 
Q2. Is there any alternate way to trace last updated date of DE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields you are referring to are not what you think they are. Last updated means: When has the dataextension itself has been updated the last time (not the records in it).

When you will rename the dataextension or add new fields or delete or alter fields the dates you are referring to will change to the current date.

There is no field that shows you when the last record has been inserted in the overview of a dataextension. If you want to know when the records have been written to the dataextension, you can add a new date field and make the default value current date.